# How to call a function inside a method in python without the 'self' argument being added?

Tags: python, function, methods, architecture

I'm developing a Django project and I'm in a situation in which I need to call a simple function from within a method:

```
def a():
    return 1

def b():
    return 2

class Report:
    def calculate(self):
        return self.method_to_call()

class Report1(Parent):
    name = 'report 1'
    description = 'report 1 desc'
    method_to_call = a

class Report2(Parent):
    name = 'report 2'
    description = 'report 2 desc'
    method_to_call = b
```

This doesn't work because python is passing the self argument to the method. How do I fix that? Should I redesign this system? If so, what would be the right way to do so? I thought this solution was the most extensible because it used a declarative syntax and the code that performs the actual calculations is separated (in another file) from the one that defines the reports and their attributes (name, description, etc...)

Comment: it is pretty difficult to understand your situation. Django follows some specific rules and your example might not necessarily work. An option for you to explore is model managers

Comment: If you want `Report1` and `Report2` to implement their own `calculate` methods, you can do that. They could inherit from `Report` and define their own `calculate` - you wouldn't need it in `Report`, which would contain all of the common stuff.

Comment: @JohnLyon I was thinking of that but it looks cleaner if the code inside the 'calculate' lives in another file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making your attributes `method_to_call` into an object attribute instead of a class attribute.

```
def a():
    return 1

def b():
    return 2

class Report:
    def calculate(self):
        return self.method_to_call()

class Report1(Report):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'report 1'
        self.description = 'report 1 desc'
        self.method_to_call = a

class Report2(Report):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'report 2'
        self.description = 'report 2 desc'
        self.method_to_call = b

print(Report1().calculate())
print(Report2().calculate())
```

Which outputs:

```
1
2
```

Comment: This helped me a lot. What I did was define an __init__ method in the parent class and set `self.value_method = self.__class__.value_method`. All other attributes can be defined outside this method without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `calculate()` a class method:

```
def a():
    return 1

def b():
    return 2

class Report:
    @classmethod
    def calculate(cls):
        return cls.method_to_call()

class Report1(Report):
    name = 'report 1'
    description = 'report 1 desc'
    method_to_call = a

class Report2(Report):
    name = 'report 2'
    description = 'report 2 desc'
    method_to_call = b


print(Report1.calculate())
print(Report2.calculate())
```

This gives:

```
1
2
```

Comment: This is great, it works even with a "@property" and requires the least amount of code.